# Using BFAST change detection algorithm for Sentinel -2 images

Tags: sentinel-2, bfast

I am interested in the BFAST change detection algorithm. I saw that this algorithm uses Landsat images.

Is it possible to use BFAST algorithm for Sentinel - 2?